# dynamic dropdown menu works at first time only in angularjs, If change the object values it won't work next time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to do a dynamic menu in angular js for my task. I am using angular 1.6 version and I mocked one JSON file and repeat that values. It works first time when I load the menu into the repeat object. But If I change that object from the controller it won't work, It won't navigate at all even all values perfect.

```
<ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-nav">
   <li uib-dropdown ng-repeat="menu in menus">
      <a ui-sref="{{menu.sref}}" class="page-scroll" href="#" uib-dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{menu.name}} <span ng-if="menu.sub_menus" class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul uib-dropdown-menu ng-if="menu.sub_menus">
            <li ui-sref-active="active-t" class="active" ng-repeat="submenu in menu.sub_menus">
               <a ui-sref="{{submenu.sref}}" class="page-scroll">
               {{submenu.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
```

And my JSON Object is :

```
"menus" : [
    {
        "name": "Feeds",
        "visible": false,
        "sref": ".feeds"
    },
    {
        "name": "Account",
        "visible": false,
        "sref": "#",
        "sub_menus": [
            {
                "name": "View Profile",
                "sref": ".view-myprofile"
            },
            {
                "name": "Edit",
                "sref": ".account"
            },
            {
                "name": "Saved Profiles",
                "sref": ".saved-profiles"
            }]}];
```

And I just debugged the code the sref values are automatically changed to camelCase. But that will work fine. The problem is first time only this submenu route nicely, If I change the object it won't work. I dont find the exact problem. Please enlighten me if i did anything wrong. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: what do you mean with change object, it reload when routing change?

Comment: Hmm. when route change, I have change the object from controller. But If I do that, That menus array getting updated. But the route won't working. 
I realized something there, the href shouldn't get update when the ui-sref change dynamically.